# What is the file "libpeerconnection.log"?

Tags: linux

I never had before the file called `libpeerconnection.log`.
If I delete it, next time that I begin a new linux session, immediately appears.
I found it in my `:~$` home folder.
I open it and the file is empty.

Anybody know if it's link by a daemon service or by a particular program?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239048. The bug is fixed in Google Chrome version 29.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome generates the file **libpeerconnection.log** in your home directory.You can make Chrome generate the file in some other directory.

Open the following file in a suitable text editor

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Add the following in a new line

`cd /tmp exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"`

to make Chrome generate libpeerconnection.log in /tmp

Comment: I had to seperate those commands. This worked for me:
`cd /tmp; exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"` or simply put the `cd /tmp` on a new line before `exec`